# Parse int or double using boost spirit (longest_d)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm looking for a way to parse a string as an int or a double, the parser should try both alternatives and choose the one matching the longest portion of the input stream.

There is a deprecated directive (longest_d) that does exactly what I'm looking for:

```
number = longest_d[ integer | real ];
```

...since it's deprecated, there are any other alternatives? In case it's necessary to implement a semantic action to achieve the desired behavior, does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firstly, do switch to Spirit V2 - which has superseded *classical* spirit for years now.

Second, you need to make sure an int gets preferred. By default, a double can parse any integer equally well, so you need to use `strict_real_policies` instead:

```
real_parser<double, strict_real_policies<double>> strict_double;
```

Now you can simply state

```
number = strict_double | int_;
```

See

- [realpolicies documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/numeric/real.html#spirit.qi.reference.numeric.real._code__phrase_role__identifier__realpolicies__phrase___code_)

See test program **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07c40aa42b49ca05)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

using A  = boost::variant<int, double>;
static real_parser<double, strict_real_policies<double>> const strict_double;

A parse(std::string const& s)
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    It f(begin(s)), l(end(s));
    static rule<It, A()> const p = strict_double | int_;

    A a;
    assert(parse(f,l,p,a));

    return a;
}

int main()
{
    assert(0 == parse("42").which());
    assert(0 == parse("-42").which());
    assert(0 == parse("+42").which());

    assert(1 == parse("42.").which());
    assert(1 == parse("0.").which());
    assert(1 == parse(".0").which());
    assert(1 == parse("0.0").which());
    assert(1 == parse("1e1").which());
    assert(1 == parse("1e+1").which());
    assert(1 == parse("1e-1").which());
    assert(1 == parse("-1e1").which());
    assert(1 == parse("-1e+1").which());
    assert(1 == parse("-1e-1").which());
}
```

Comment: It's possible that I don't understand the scenario of the question but wouldn't `number=double_|int_` just work?

Comment: @llonesmiz Yes, real_parser<double,strict_real_policies<double>>()|int_ works fine too.

Comment: Doesn't `(int_ - double_)` always fail to parse, because every int can be parsed as a double?

Comment: Shouldn't the order be reversed to `number = strict_double | int_`? Assuming it tries to parse from left to right.

Comment: @UndefinedPavel You're absolutely right, of course. Added a test program now with the fixed version :) (_The ordering was a relict from an older version of this answer. Apparently, I managed to fudge it twice..._)