# boost::spirit::qi::double_ and boost::spirit::qi::int_

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

How to parse a string which may contain either double or int depending on whether the dot is set. E.g. 6.0 is of double type and 6 is of int type. The rule would be

```
rule<it,boost::variant<int,double>,skipper> r = qi::double_|qi::int_;
```

However, a stream will be fed by double as for all numbers in this case.

Comment: related: ["Parse int or double using boost spirit"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13261502/2378523)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the pragmatic approach<sup>1</sup> given by interjay, have a look at `real_parser_policies`:

```
real_parser<double,strict_real_policies<double>>() | int_
```

would be equally good.

---

<sup>1</sup> which I sometimes use myself (you should be able to find [an answer doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+%5Bboost-spirit%5D) on SO). Note, however that there *are* problems when the input is e.g. `123e-5` (which would parse an int, leaving `e-5` unparsed).

Comment: 123e-5 should be parsed: floating_literal
    =   -sign >>
        (       nan
            |   inf
            |   fractional_constant >> !exponent_part
            |  +digit >> exponent_part
        )
    ;exponent_part
    =   (lit('e') | 'E') >> -sign >> +digit
    ;

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
(int_ >> !lit('.')) | double_
```

It will match an integer only if it isn't followed by a dot. Otherwise, it will match a double.

Comment: If you want less heavy backtracking, use the strict real policy

Comment: Also, -1 as this answer does not work correctly for Inf/NaN/exponential notation (think about `1e10`, e.g.)