# boost spirit x3 int32 | double_ fails to parse double

Tags: c++, parsing, c++14, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I am trying to write a parser, which parses either a `int32_t` or a `double`.
As a first try I wrote this parser:

```
const auto int_or_double = boost::spirit::x3::int32 | boost::spirit::x3::double_;
```

which I expect to get back a `boost::variant<int32_t, double>`
the parser succeed to parse ints like `12, 100, -42, 7` but it fails to parse doubles like `13.243, 42.7, 12.0 -10000.3`

here is a live [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c3d5adbf6857228)

Why does this parser fail on doubles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261502/parse-int-or-double-using-boost-spirit-longest-d).

When the integer parser occurs first in your grammar, it is preferred. For the input `"12.9"` the parser will parse the integer part of `"12.9` which is `12` and will stop at the `.`. <kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/580ba878885ce97c)</kbd>

You have to reverse the order so the double parser is preferred over the integer one:

```
const auto double_or_int =  boost::spirit::x3::double_ | boost::spirit::x3::int32;
```

This will now work for `"12.9"`: <kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56acdb965ae4f0a6)</kbd>

However, since a double parser also parses an integer, you will always get a double, even if the input is `"12"`:  <kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cae3a6ce2a5dc3c)</kbd>

In order to prevent this, you need a strict double parser:

```
boost::spirit::x3::real_parser<double, boost::spirit::x3::strict_real_policies<double> > const double_ = {};
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/859581a2f4392796)</kbd>

Comment: wow thank you I didn't know about the `strict_real_policies` template

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know about `strict_real_policies` either, that sounds handy.

I worked around this in a more direct way once like so:

```
(qi::int_ >> !lit('.') >> !lit('e') >> !lit('E')) | qi::float_
```

If you have a look at the flow chart on http://www.json.org/
you can see that those three characters cover all the legal ways that a number could be caused to parse as a float. (In my particular problem.)

Comment: That approach will usually work, but in a case like [this one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07be3ea0e2824259) it would fail. If you know that the integer part will never be missing, I think that `(int_ >> !char_(".eE")) | float_` should be equivalent and (slightly) less noisy.

Comment: That's forgetting about skippers, so it should likely become `lexeme[int_ >> !char_(".eE")] | double_`

Comment: @sehe: In the grammar I was working in, I disabled all skippers. The full rule was actually `non_nil_value = true_ | false_ | (qi::int_ >> !lit('.') >> !lit('e') >> !lit('E')) | qi::float_ | tstring_ | lua_string_ | table;`. But yeah in general I guess `lexeme` should be involved.